# Trying to pull API into LinearLayout Android APP

Tags: android, xml, api, android-layout

I am a beginner of Android apps and am using Eclipse.  I have found some larger samples of pulling APIs but I cannot find a simple one to get started with.  I simply want to pull from an XML file on the web (by using an API KEY) and throw it in a LinearLayout (Vertical).  I can then go from there, anyone know of any?  Below is a sample of my XML:

```
<xmldata>
 <Products>
   <ProductCode>ITI-GR12</ProductCode>
   <ProductName>Granada 9-3/4" Narrow Rim Platter</ProductName>
   <ProductPrice>64.4000</ProductPrice>
 </Products>
</xmldata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for mechanisms which help you to parse XML and extract data from it...Voila here is a link to get you started with different ways of doing it...

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

your question is not easy as you will have quite a lot of programming to achieve what you want.

Here are the steps :

1. read your data using sax
2. fill a data structure of your own (build a
   class, data members will be filled by
   previous parsing)
3. build an activity, use a layout you define to
   show all UI fields you think you need
   to display your data
4. fill the   content of each view using the data
   structure you filled on step 2.

If you are a beginner, I suggest you first understand steps 3 and 4, having fun with UIs, then try to understand how you could download your file, parse it and fill some data class to provide content for the views.

Regards,
 Stéphane